# Не считывает информацию из XML файла

Tags: c#, юнит-тесты

Выполняю UnitTest.Есть XML файл. Хочу считывать с него данные

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<UserDetails>
   <User inkContainerValue="1000" sizeLetter="1.0" color="Blue" />
</UserDetails>
```

вот код самого теста

```
public TestContext TestContext { get; set; }
[DataSource("Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.DataSource.XML", "TestData.xml", "User", DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
[TestMethod]
public void TestColor_shouldCreatObject()
{
   int inkContainerValue = Convert.ToInt32(TestContext.DataRow["inkContainerValue"]);
   double sizeLetter = Convert.ToDouble(TestContext.DataRow["sizeLetter"]);
   string color = Convert.ToString(TestContext.DataRow["color"]);
   Pen pen = new Pen(inkContainerValue, sizeLetter, color);    
   Assert.IsNotNull(pen);
}
```

ошибки не выдаёт, но из файла не читает.

Comment: Используйте класс `XDocument`

Comment: @Sv__t для создания XML?

Comment: Для начала, попробуйте `Convert.ToDouble(TestContext.DataRow["sizeLetter"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`.

Comment: А вы установили копирование в выходной каталог для ваших xml-файлов?

Comment: @VladD да, установил

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov а что есть CultureInfo.InvariantCulture?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка была в том, что Convert.ToDouble не переводит из Object в Double(как я понял разные стандарты написания дробных чисел). `Convert.ToDouble(TestContext.DataRow["sizeLetter"], CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` действительно помогло.